# Popular questions by view count

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stackexchange

I made [this query](http://data.stackexchange.com/codereview/revision/335479/433345/popular-questions-by-view-count) to create a graph of a user's popular questions and the view count on that question. It allows for a minimum of `500` views, and a score of `3`.

```
DECLARE @allowed_min_views INT = 500;
DECLARE @allowed_min_score INT = 3;

DECLARE @user_id INT = ##UserId:int?-1##;
DECLARE @min_views INT = ##MinimumViews:int?500##;
DECLARE @min_score INT = ##MinimumScore:int?3##;
DECLARE @question INT = 1;

IF (@min_views < @allowed_min_views)
BEGIN
  PRINT '@MinimumViews must be larger than 499.'
END

IF (@min_score < @allowed_min_score)
BEGIN
  PRINT '@MinimumScore must be larger than 2.'
END

IF (@min_views >= @allowed_min_views AND @min_score >= @allowed_min_score)
BEGIN
  SELECT
      ViewCount
    , Score
    FROM Posts WHERE
      PostTypeId = @question
      AND OwnerUserId = @user_id
      AND ViewCount >= @min_views
      AND Score >= @min_score
    ORDER BY ViewCount ASC;
END
```

Finally, here's some sample input (I'm using [@Mat'sMug](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/23788/mats-mug)'s user ID):

```
@user_id:   23788
@min_views: 500
@min_score: 7
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Good things

You use good local variables, and you are consistent with your naming. The *typical* naming for T-SQL is using `PascalCase`, however there are no standards and `snake_case` or `camelCase` work just as good, as long as you are consistent (which you are).

You validate your values, although I am not quite sure why you chose 500 and 3 as arbitrary minimums (might be worth documenting).

---

#### Results are not very useful...

As written, your query returns this:

```
ViewCount Score 
--------- ----- 
571       10    
629       5     
685       6     
721       10    
728       11    
761       12    
840       25    
849       7     
870       17    
888       9     
1065      10
...
```

Which is all well and good, except, it doesn't give much information. Let's say we rewrite it a bit like this:

```
IF (@min_views >= @allowed_min_views AND @min_score >= @allowed_min_score)
BEGIN
  SELECT
      ViewCount
    , Score
    , [User Link] = @user_id
    , [Post Link] = Id
    , CreationDate
    , [Tags] = Tags
    FROM Posts 
    WHERE
      PostTypeId = @question
      AND OwnerUserId = @user_id
      AND ViewCount >= @min_views
      AND Score >= @min_score
    ORDER BY ViewCount DESC;
END
```

*Notice I changed `ORDER BY` to `DESC`, I think it makes more sense to show highest first.*

Then we get a [more sensible result set](http://data.stackexchange.com/codereview/query/335501/popular-questions-by-view-count?UserId=-1&MinViews=500&MinScore=3), e.g.:

[image]

Comment: I used `ASC` because it made more sense to have lower views first on a graph.

Comment: Ah OK. I didn't see a graph generated by your query so I didn't know

Answer (score 5):

> ```
> DECLARE @allowed_min_views INT = 500;
> DECLARE @allowed_min_score INT = 3;
> ```

This feels very user unfriendly.  What is the reasoning for this limit?

---

> ```
> SELECT
>     ViewCount
>   , Score
>   FROM Posts WHERE
>     PostTypeId = @question
>     AND OwnerUserId = @user_id
>     AND ViewCount >= @min_views
>     AND Score >= @min_score
>   ORDER BY ViewCount ASC;
> ```

Most queries don't indent the `FROM` any farther than the `SELECT` and put the `WHERE` in its own line as well.  Otherwise, this looks good to me.

Answer (score 2):

I like symmetry. It's a bit off-putting to see `PascalCase` symbols (the column names in the SE tables) and `snake_case` symbols (your variables) mixed together. It would be better to adjust to the given style, and use `PascalCase` for your variables.

The variable `@question` is a bit misleading. It's not a "question", not even a "question id", it's actually the id of the question type. So `@QuestionTypeId` would be a more natural name.

Finally, the requirement of a user id is not very user friendly. Everybody knows @Mat's Mug but I doubt many people know that he also goes by 23788. Sure, it's not too hard to look that up, but it still takes a few clicks per user. It would be better to allow lookups by either user name or user id.